# Loading up data from a SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table with rows in the millions. I need to process all of them in a program.

I am interested in only one column which is `studentId`. How do I write a query to load up 2000 of those items and then feed it to the program to process and then get the next batch of 2000 and so on?

The problem is how do I keep track of which items I have already processed, the list isn't sorted.

EDIT: The process I need to do is this: 
I have a table in the form of  [studentId, name, DepartmentId]

The number of students here could easily be 30 to 40 million. The various departments that they belong to typically could be in order of thousands...So DepartmentId's could be in the range of 5000 to 6000. The rows could be interspersed.
Now I need to get all students belonging to a specific department, and process them in a program. I cannot load a million student ids at once, so i need to do some sort of batching.
Thanks.

Comment: You can do it manually using ROW_NUMBER rn... WHERE rn BETWEEN x and y Put that in a loop and you increment the variables by 2000 for each iteration

Comment: What sort of process do you have to do?

Comment: Hi @DanBracuk, I added an Edit.

Comment: Which front end technology you are using???

Answer (score 0):

If that is MYSQL you can do something like this

```
SELECT studentId from [TABLE_NAME] LIMIT 0,2000
```

you just need to loop around your code or SP to and change the `LIMIT` numbers.

Comment: But it's sql server.  Read the tags.

Answer (score 0):

If we run our select multiple times, SQL Server doesn't guarantee to have the same order in the results.

So you have two choices:

1. Order the table and use `OFFSET FETCH` clause. ( or use `TOP` clause, but `TOP` isn’t a standard feature). You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` with `OVER`. But in this case `OFFSET` is simpler and better for performance.
2. Or use your ID key in `WHERE` clause (`WHERE BETWEEN`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `SqlDataReader`, read each batch, process it, and keep reading, until you finish. Only close the reader when you finish all the batches.

You can [change the isolation level if locking is a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341590/how-to-set-isolation-level-on-sqlcommand-sqlconnection-initialized-with-no-trans).